# Why use typedef for declaring a structure?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)

Is there a difference between

```
typedef struct{
....
} mystruct;
```

and

```
struct mystruct{
....
};
```

?

Comment: it's a habit from `c`...

Comment: @mwigdahl yeah sorry, didn't see that one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, the syntax to declare a struct is `struct mystruct var;`, so developers often typedef an anonymous struct to make declaring as simple as `mystruct var;`. C++ allows you to define structs without the `struct` keyword, so the typedef is used less often.

Answer (score 1):

It's useless in C++. In C, it's because structs have their own namespace (you need to write `struct T` if you don't typedef to something else).

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference in C++.

Answer (score 0):

This idiom is commonly used in C, where a struct variable would need to be declared as `struct StructName myStruct`, and `StructName myStruct` wouldn't work.  It's not necessary in C++.